# Receiving an email on nodemon events (error, restart)?

Tags: node.js, docker, email, nodemon, monit

my nodemon is running inside a docker-container, `ENTRYPOINT yarn start` runs nodemon.
 **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./src/bin/www"
}
```

Basically, changes I make in app.js are being watched, when I run docker-compose up. app.js is running on a server, requests data from an API every 5 minutes and stores it in mongoDB.

Sometimes, it happens that nodemon crashes which interrupts the requests to the API.

I want to receive an email whenever nodemon crashes, restarts or throws an error regardless of the code.

Found this in the documentation:
https://github.com/remy/nodemon#triggering-events-when-nodemon-state-changes

> For example, to trigger a notification on a Mac when nodemon restarts, nodemon.json looks like this:
>
> ````
>   "events": {
>     "restart": "osascript -e 'display notification \"app restarted\" with title \"nodemon\"'"
>   }
> }```
> ````

What would be a good practice?
Can I use Monit https://mmonit.com/monit/ for my purpose? I already used it for watching my docker containers but I'm not sure how to proceed for nodemon events. Or is there a better way?

Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Can you describe the setup a little more?  In which environment is it possible for the code in the container to change, but also need to be notified of it?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added a couple of facts, hope that'll help.